# Is it possible to remove a border from a Webm video losslessly?

Tags: mkv

I know that Matroska does have a way to remove the border by editing its metadata, and i also know that Webm is a cheaper version of Matroska. I have tried using MKVtools to edit Webm and it appears to work, but then when i play the file nothing changes.

So does Webm support metadata removal of border from the video? If it does what tool can i use to perform this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here https://www.webmproject.org/docs/container/ under section Track. There you find PixelCropBottom, PixelCropTop, PixelCropLeft and PixelCropRight - all of which are supported. These parameters should do what you want. They also exist for Matroska.

Look for a tool that can manipulate those parameters.

Comment: `-vf` will still reencode the video stream, will it not?

Comment: Yes. I'll edit my answer and remove it. I've no other idea what tool to use at the moment.

Comment: Thanks. I have checked it, and MKVtools can do that, and i guess i've been doing that.... however, the players simply do not respect that those parameters.

Comment: If you use a browser, like Chrome, and open the webm video there, does it work then? Maybe some or many players have not implemented this feature as it is probably not used much.

Comment: Yeah, I currently use SeaMonkey, and it works there, but only if i put not only crop values, but also display values.